# Web app protected by single password for all clients

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I was wondering if there is a standard way of protecting a ASP.Net web application with just a single password? In other words no username needed and all clients use the same password for authentication.
Or does anyone have their own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply could use Identity framework to aim this propose. Actually you don't need any user or password to authenticate.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string password)
{
    if (password=="MyVerySecretPassword")
    {
        var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[] { 
                // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "JustAnuniqueName"),
              new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,"JustAnuniqueName"),
          },
          DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); // auth succeed 
     }
     // invalid password
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
     return View();
}
```

But it would be much better if you hash the password and check the hashed password instead of above simple `if` statement. To aim this you could use `PasswordHasher` class to hash and verify the password.

First hash your desired password and save it in preferred storage (DB, file, hard coded in code or everywhere else):

```
string hashedPassword = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword("MyVerySecretPassword");
```

Now since you have the hashed one. You could use `VerifyHashedPassword()` method to verify it.

```
if(new PasswordHasher()
    .VerifyHashedPassword("myHashedPassword",password)==PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
{
    // the password is correct do whatever you want
}
```

Also you could see my [simple working example](https://github.com/samfgl/TokenBasedAuthenticationSample) which I made to demonstrate it.

Comment: I implemented this in an existing application and it works! Thx! There are some things i would like to know though. 
*The ClaimTypes Name and NameIdentifier, do these have to be unique for every client? 
*Is there a way for making this solution more secure?
*Is there a way of checking if the client already has a cookie and in that case let the user skip login procedure?

Thx!

Comment: `Name` claim mostly is used to show user name. And `NameIdentifier` is used as a username so it is preferred to be unique. But in your case you could use the same username for all of your clients because actually you have one user in your app. Also you can check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property to see if the current user authenticated or not.

Comment: Thx! So is there a way to make this even more secure?

Comment: It is actually secure now. We are using a secure method to authorize our app. But it would be much better to avoid use plain password and use hashed password instead. I've updated the post to show how.

Comment: Do i need to use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() with my forms? Are there any other necessary steps for preventing xsrf attacks? Im using ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 now.

Comment: Yes you need to use antiforgery token when you submit a form to prevent xsrf attacks.